# How to get unread emails from email app(not Gmail)

Tags: java, android, email, authentication, accountmanager

im working on a Widget that displays the unread E-Mail Count of Gmail and other E-Mail Accounts set in the Smartphone. I'm using the Google-Mail Api for Gmail and it works finde, but i didnt get how to work with the normal E-Mail App.

I tried to use the Account Manager to get Login-Credentials and retrieve infromation by myself, but it didnt run because i cant get any password or so. Just Auth-Tokens. I cant find any solution on google on how to work with normal email accounts their are not from google-mail.

UPDATE:
Im trying to get the password with this function but i get an Error:
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
        for(Account account : accounts){
            String test = AccountManager.get(context).getPassword(account);
            System.out.println(account.name+" "+test);
        }

"cannot get secrets for Accounts of type: com.android.exchange"

Thanks,
j Doe ;)

Answer (score 1):

> but i didnt get how to work with the normal E-Mail App

There is no single "normal E-Mail App". You are welcome to contact the developers of various email apps and ask them if they have documented and supported APIs for what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you have a clean android isntallation there is an app called "E-Mail" that will display all your E-Mail inboxed(Gmail and also other ones added via smtp /imap /pop3)

Comment: @J.Doe: Not every device has this app. For example, my Nexus 5X, running Android 6.0.1, does not have an app named "E-Mail". Nor does a Nexus 6P (Android 6.0.1) or a Nexus 9 (Android 7.0), just to list a few that I happen to have powered on and nearby.